# Android - button element is hidden when adding list fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to write a layout that will contain a list view and a button in an Android layout. The list view is a fragment and the button is part of the layout.

**layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- fragment container to display transactions for this budget -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/transactionsContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newTransaction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_new_transaction"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**listview_fragment.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transactionTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/transactionAmount"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/transactionAmount"
        style="@style/ListItemDescription"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transactionAmount"
        style="@style/AmountText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm adding the fragment like this;

```
final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment container = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.transactionsContainer);

if (container == null) {
    final TransactionListFragment fragment = new TransactionListFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.transactionsContainer, fragment).commit();
}
```

The fragment is added to the layout just fine, however, when the list grows bigger than the display height the button is missing. If there are a small number of list view items, then the button is visible;

**Button visible with 3 items**

[image]

**Button missing with 10 items**

[image]

When debugging the view with the hierarchyviewer, the Button is present but looks as if it is behind the listview fragment;

[image]

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Use `layout_weight` attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- fragment container to display transactions for this budget -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/transactionsContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newTransaction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_new_transaction"/>a

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however when trying this, only one item appears in the list view. Having read the [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) docs, it says you should not use a ScrollView with a ListView as the ListView takes care of its own scrolling

Comment: @Kevin, yes, it's true, then you have another option. See update. Button will be always at bottom, list view will be scroll inside `transactionsContainer`

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's nearly what I was looking for. Rather than it being at fixed position at the bottom of the screen, I wanted it to appear at the bottom of the layout - so it comes into view after scrolling has finished. Is there a way to make the fragment, the first child of the linear layout when adding it? If so, I may be able to add the button as part of the LinearLayout.

Comment: Exists several options: move button into fragment as footer of ListView, other is to use ScrollView, but replace list view by full list view (it shows all items during drawing)

Answer (score 0):

give a weight to your layout transactionsContainer so that you force it to not fill the entire height in the case of many items, and wrap it in a ScrollView to scroll through items while there is a lot of them:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:weightSum="10">

    <!-- fragment container to display transactions for this budget --> 
    <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/transactionsContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newTransaction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button_new_transaction"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and when adding a view to the ScrollView during the run-time:

```
transactionsContainer.addView(view, 0);
```

Comment: This kind of works. Adding a weight to the container and button does show the button, but it's positioned fixed at the bottom of the screen (regardless of scrolling). I'd like it to appear after scrolling has ended.

Comment: So, simply remove the Button from the layout and add it dynamically through the run-time as the last item of the ScrollView/ListView

Comment: I made an edit to the updated solution, take it into account, just add the Button also in the LinearLayout and when adding something to it, consider adding it at index = 0, so that it will be above the Button